# Adding user roles in runtime for ASP.NET Core API authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-identity

My API is using `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` and the `HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated` has `True` on its value, so I can use `[Authorize]` on my controllers.

But now I want to use role based authentication, like `[Authorize(Policy = "TestPolicy")]`. I added the desired policies on my `Startup.cs` using `AddAuthorization(...)` extension.

The requests are returning `code 403` (unauthorized), because the HttpContext.User.Identity.Roles is not populated.

I created a middleware to populate this property, and I can get the roles of the user with `UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user)`. Now I have a list of user roles, but how can I add then to the curent `HttpContext.User` so the user could be authorized with the policies I added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating jwt store role in the jwt as a claim, and create a permission requirement:

```
public class PermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
        {

            if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "role" && c.Value =
 requirement.Permission))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("User  has required permission: " + requirement.Permission);
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("User is forbidden");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

checkout following for details:

https://github.com/adnan-kamili/AspNetCore-Web-Api-Rest-Starter-Kit

Comment: Nice starter kit you have, taking many details into consideration.